# Bonding yourself via GND pin of an USB-port?

Tags: usb, safety, esd, ground-plane, antistatic

A simple EPA ([ESD Protected Area](https://vermasonesd.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/what-is-an-esd-protected-area-epa/)) consists of 3 things:

- wrist strap
- antistatic mat
- common point ground

When doing field service (installing/replacing hardware parts) the ESD sensitive part goes straight into a static shielding bag and the replacement part comes out of a static shielding bag and goes straight into the PC. You only need a wrist strap to bond yourself to the PC.

[image]

On a desktop PC you can connect to the conductive case. Laptops on the other hand often have a non-conductive plastic housing.

Bonding to the ground pin of an USB port is an alternative option. This means: reaching equipotential with the motherboard's ground-plane via the USB port.

[image]

- Can the USB port and/or motherboard handle the current spike? ESD damage?
- What about user safety?
- Should there be a resistor between PC and wrist strap?

[image: an USB port]
<sub>(source: [usb3.com](https://www.usb3.com/usb2-Apinout-600.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Does your wrist strap have a a series resistor built in (1 Meg for example)?

Comment: Many laptops aren't grounded.  There's nowhere for the discharge to go - you are just equalizing your charge with the charge from the laptop.

Comment: @jagjordi No, my wrist strap does not have a series R built in. Often, the R is inside the coil cord between wrist strap and whatever you connect it to.

Comment: @JRE You're right. I edited my question. You are discharging yourself to the laptop until all charge is distributed evenly over all things that are bonded together. Without resistor, this happens almost instantly, resulting in a current spike. I would guess an USB port can handle this, but i really want to be sure before blowing out the USB port and/or causing ESD damage to the motherboard.

Comment: USB ports will have TVS protection diodes, specifically because the normal user is more than likely to touch one of the ports during use probably causing an ESD strike in the process. Same goes for plugging in any device - e.g. a USB memory stick will have some static charge which needs to be equalised when it is plugged in.

Answer (score 7):

You should NOT connect your anti-static gears to USB ground pin. The USB ground is SIGNAL GROUND. An ESD event can surge along the signal ground and elevate its potential relative to other ICs inputs (called sometimes as "ground bounce"), and it can damage internal ICs. If you don't have Earth ground on your workspace, at most you should use SHIELD of the USB connector, but not GND. The SHIELD usually is properly designed to re-direct and absorb the surge without exposing internal low-votage CMOS ICs to dangerous voltages.

Comment: +1 Good point about causing damage to the system ground.  If you get two ESD spikes in a row then who knows what will happen on the second one?!

Comment: @ali-chen Thanks. I edited my question. Is the GND pin not just the ground for the power? Then D- should be the signal ground? You can even buy [special USB Ground Adapters](http://documents.desco.com/PDF/09839.pdf), which only connect to the GND pin, if i'm correct.

Comment: @Marty, D- is not any kind of ground at all.  Go read up about how USB works.

Comment: I fail to see how an ESD into the USB ground can damage anything. The discharge will essentially go through the ground plane and the laptop chassis.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You think it's perfectly safe?

Comment: @Marty Make a continuity test to be sure. In the laptops I've taken apart, USB GND was directly connected to the PCB ground plane which then makes contact with the rest of the laptop via screws and copper braids.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Thanks. A continuity test will only make sure whether the GND-pin is connected to the ground-plane. (That is probably true.) Can you connect the wrist strap to the USB-port without a resistor in between?

Comment: A resistor is there essentially to protect **you**, if you happen to touch a live wire while wearing a wrist band connected to neutral via Earth. Since you won't be connecting to Earth, you can do without, but I would still put one if possible. Imagine someone could reuse your strap with a real Earth and get electrocuted: a resistor which could potentially save their life suddenly doesn't seem useless, right?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, indeed, you're right :-) But, technically and theoretically, that resistor isn't serving any purpose in this use case, which is: equipotential bonding. Right? Without a resistor, the user can't get a shock from the laptop?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, ESD into signal ground (even if it is a solid plane) selects certain path (of lesser resistance) to Earth-grounded shield (or more massive part of non-grounded device). The ESD kilo-volts will sill apply across the ground. If some other IC is residing in a far corner of mainboard, its IO pins will be referenced to the unaffected level, but can be connected to the IC that was "bounced" due to ESD. This may create a potentially damaging delta-V for the far-residing IC. Limiting resistor in a ESD strap, however, will help to reduce the bounce.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop probably has an isolated power supply. Does it have this symbol?

[image]

This means everything inside the laptop is isolated from the power outlet, including USB ground. Connecting your wrist strap to will not connect it to Earth, so you will still be able to produce ESD with equipment not connected to the laptop.

This is in contrast with desktop PCs whose cases are connected to protective Earth:

[image]

Connecting your strap to their cases will work as expected: you will be at the same potential with all grounded equipment in your lab.

Comment: Indeed. Connecting your wrist strap to the (GND pin of an) USB-port will not connect it to earth. The wrist strap gets bonded to the laptop, correct? The charge on my body will distribute over my body and the laptop. Result: equipotential between me and the laptop.

Comment: @Marty Yes, that is correct. You won't be able to shock your laptop if you're connected to it via USB GND.

Comment: Can an USB port handle the charge coming from the wrist strap? The moment you plug in your wrist strap into an USB port there will be a current spike.

Comment: Obviously yes, since it can handle those spikes when you plug regular USB devices. If you're pedantic, use USB shield instead of USB GND, but a continuity test will almost certainly tell you they are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. But, generally, there isn't a 4kV (or more) potential difference between these regular USB devices and the USB port, right?

Comment: @Marty Sparks in dry air appear at about 40 kV/cm, and I certainly have seen sparks exceeding 1mm.

Answer (score 0):

ESD will take the path of **least impedance**, not simple DC resistance.  It is, after all, a transient high speed event. So while the ground pin on the USB port may have DC continuity, it is not the ideal path to dissipate electric charge.

The metal shroud on a USB A connector provides a low impedance path to the chassis and/or chassis plane. The chassis connections are much more tolerant to ESD events, it's what they are designed for.