# Can I safely ground myself by clipping an anti-static wristband to a half-inserted plug?

Tags: safety, grounding, esd

I'm having some trouble grounding myself for laptop repair. I cannot get the crocodile clip of my anti-static wristband in to my plug socket (I'm in the UK, so our sockets are a bit difficult) and I can't find a non-painted part of any of my radiators to clip myself to.

This has made me a bit desperate, but I've found a solution. Is it safe to get a normal plug, insert it about halfway in to a switched-off plug socket, and clip the crocodile clip of my anti-static wristband to the half-inserted ground prong of the plug?

Comment: get a scrap PC power supply ... plug it into a power outlet ... clip your wristband to the power supply case

Comment: DON'T do any of this stuff. UK mains sockets are nice and difficult to stick wires into - which is why we value them. Do it properly, either running an earth wire out of a closed mains plug (see answer below) or go and buy a proper ESD earthing mains plug. Don't take chances.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to accidentally come in contact with a hot wire and kill yourself... Use a water pipe instead.

Comment: @MadHatter A water pipe? Those things outside of my house?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bad idea. The pin may not be making contact internally in the socket. You also risk contacting the live pin on an older plug.

[image]

*Figure 1. The earth pin of a UK 13A plugtop.*

Instead, get a length of insulated wire, strip off about 6 mm and terminate it in the earth pin and run it through the cable clamp - maybe looping around it so that it grips the single core adequately.

Then refit the back of the mains plug and screw it closed, so the mains Live and Neutral pins are safely inaccessible.

Strip a cm of insulation from the other end and connect your wristband to that. Make sure that your wriststrap has a resistor in circuit to reduce the possibility of electric shock should you touch a live part.

Comment: What cable clamp?

Comment: OK, maybe you shouldn't do this yourself.

Comment: @J.Mini The cable clamp is the white piece of plastic at the center bottom of the rightmost picture. It's held in place by screws, and holds tight to the incoming cable. Google "strain relief". If someone yanks on the cable, the strain will be felt by the cable clamp instead of the electrified screw terminals. If you take one if these apart, you'll see what Transistor is talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Put the clip to your laptop. It does not help if you ground yourself and the laptop is ungrounded so there can be potential difference between you and laptop.

Comment: I agree, but there's no metal that I know of on my laptop.

Comment: no USB sockets? no video connectors? how is it charged?  in any case once you get the cover off there will be plenty of metal.

Comment: @Jasen I've checked if that's possible, and it appears to be, but this answer says that it's a bad idea and I may have caused damage by doing said checking https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/296503/239962

Answer (score 2):

I would not do that.

My experience with UK plugs is that you can easily remove the two power prongs.
That would give you a much safer access to the ground pin.

Comment: How would that change anything? I'd still be just as clipped the ground prong as I was before.

Comment: Plugging halfway has the risk of accidentally still making contact. This way you would not have ANY dangerous voltage inside you plug.

Comment: That makes sense. Should I take the back off the plug?

Comment: With most UK plugs all the metal prongs are held in place with the back-cover. If you omit it, the ground prong is likely to fall out.

Comment: @Oldfart, please correct me if I'm wrong but would removing the two power prongs create a single pin plug that would plug into any of the three openings in the power outlet?

Comment: Good remark :@jsotola but: No, the ground pin is bigger in size and does not fit in any of the power openings. Also in the UK the power openings are 'covered' and the cover is removed when the ground pin is pushed in (it is a bit longer then the power pins). This also makes them safe for children: when there is no plug a child can not 'poke' a metal object in the power holes.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. you should start with a grounded work surface and attach yourself to that.

you can ground yourself to a power outlet. but that doesn't protect  your laptop unless it is also grounded, and any parts being removed or added should als be grounded at the same time.

if you want to connect to mains ground connect to a grounded appliance, (eg, a toaster) connected to a socket that is turned off, but for ESD prevention really most of the battle is getting the work and the work surface and the worker to all be at the same potential