# Bonding yourself via oscilloscope GND?

Tags: esd, antistatic

I want to prevent ESD and I read that connecting the wrist band to i.e. USB ground [is not a good idea](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296201/bonding-yourself-via-gnd-pin-of-an-usb-port). My oscilloscope has a test output where I would like to connect the aligator clamp of the ESD wrist band to ground. Will this harm the scope?

How about the measurements with the scope? I would start measuring only after connecting the wrist band. I assume that I charge myself only slowly so there should be no spikes *after* connecting that could affect the measurements. Is that right?

[image]

Comment: Don't you have $10 to spend on a proper ESD bonding point?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Thanks. This seems to be the better idea. 'proper' is the keyword...

Answer (score 0):

Usually that ground is chassis ground, and also connected to the back. You can ohm it out from that point to the middle pin of the mains connector on the back. Make sure you use a 1MegΩ resistor inbetween the strap and ground to protect against a fault.